# How to remove borders from the Ajax Loading Icon in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

is there way to remove this borders from the default jquery mobile loading icon?

I'm trying to call the ajax-loading.gif icon before any page creation.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '[data-role="page"]', function () {
     $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function () {
     $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

The only change I made to the .css file is the following:

```
.ui-page, body {
      background: transparent !important;
}
```

Thanks

[image: jQuery Mobile loading icon]

Comment: by default it should not have a border...

Comment: Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/yVzVeq, as you see, by default there is no border. Are you using a third party theme or CSS that might be overriding the .ui-loader class?

Answer (score 0):

you could check wether it has an id or not and try to set the borders to 0 via CSS. But my guess is that the border comes with the icon so you would have to replace the icon with a borderless one.